# Implementing NSCopying on custom UIView objects

Tags: ios, nscopying

I have an view which has image view as it's `subView` and have property which has reference to some object(`delegate` object). I am confused with implementing `copyWithZone:` for this object.

While, I am trying to use like `[copy setDelegate:[[self delegate] copyWithZone:zone]]` compiler reports an error.

Is it possible to copy the gesture recognizers added to the view. So that when I deserialize the object from file, I can use the object directly.

Comment: I can't be sure, but this feels very circular, you are copying your delegate, and then assigning that copy as your copy's delegate...   Would you mind posting the code surrounding this for some context into what you're trying to accomplish?